# Compiling Bootstrap less files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, less

I read the in the 'Getting Started' page on bootstrap's website that we need to have Autoprefixer and Grunt.

What are these and how do I use them when I'm compiling the Bootstrap's less files?

I was able to compile the Less file (bootstrap.less) into the CSS file using the Prepos program but I was still not sure if I was using the Autoprefixer or even Grunt.

My System and Program:

**OS:** Lubuntu 15.04 64 bit
**Text Editor:** Sublime Text
**Program Installed:** node.js, less, grunt-cli

Answer (score 0):

[Autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) and [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) are Node packages available via NPM.

I'd recommend starting with Grunt's getting started guide: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started